# Read CSV files with SSRS

Tags: csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Apparently, Microsoft has discontinued support for Oracle Hyperion Essbase in SSRS, so we can't read directly from the original database.

We devised a solution by exporting our data to csv file, and then read them in SSRS. But it doesn't work.

I tried to create a new OLEDB datasource in SSRS, with those parameters :

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="\\server\share";Extended Properties="text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited(,)"
```

But it throws an error... "Unspecified error". I have tried many things, but to no avail.

Does anyone has any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You might need the 64 bit OLEDB drivers? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Already checked ; already installed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS still supports ODBC connections. I know it's a bit old-school but it would be better than using an intermediary file format to transfer data. You might need to edit the listener.ora on the Oracle server.
I've used ODBC for all sorts of weird database connections that don't have decent OLEDB drivers or aren't supported.